# Add empty columns to data to be filled later

Tags: r

At the end of a for loop (which is a for loop along "trials"), I run the following code. All it's doing is creating a column to store the data, but trials is prespecified so I can set them up before the loop. This bit of code alone is taking the code 17% longer, and any bit helps. Is there an easy/fast way to set up the columns ahead of the loop using the number of trials (*numtrials*)?

```
  ptptdata[[paste0("FinalSalary_",trial)]]<-ptptdata$FinalSalary
  ptptdata[[paste0("FinalDCBalance_",trial)]]<-ptptdata$FinalDCBalance
  ptptdata[[paste0("FinalAge_",trial)]]<-ptptdata$FinalAge
  ptptdata[[paste0("FinalSSLow_",trial)]]<-ptptdata$FinalSSLow
  ptptdata[[paste0("FinalSSHigh_",trial)]]<-ptptdata$FinalSSHigh
```

I would also need to copy them, but I'm guessing `ptptdata$FinalSalary_trial <- ptptdata$FinalSalary` won't work because it won't recognize trial as a variable. How do I reference a variable after a $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy all the columns directly in one line -

```
cols <- c('FinalSalary','FinalDCBalance','FinalAge','FinalSSLow', 'FinalSSHigh')
new_cols <- paste(cols, trial, sep = '_')
ptptdata[new_cols] <- ptptdata[cols]
```

The above code will still go in the loop.

If you want to create all the columns before executing the loop, try :

```
#Assuming trial is 1:3
trials <- 1:3 
new_cols <- c(outer(cols, trials, paste, sep = '_'))
ptptdata[new_cols] <- ptptdata[cols]
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, I think the second part would work perfectly. I would also need to copy them, but I'm guessing ptptdata$FinalSalary_trial <- ptptdata$FinalSalary won't work because it won't recognize trial as a variable. How do I reference a variable after a $?

Comment: `ptptdata[new_cols] <- ptptdata[cols]` should copy that. Did you try that?

Comment: You're completely right. Worked like a charm. Thanks so much! Upvoted and marked as correct